React Native smooth image transition
(Example video)
In React-Native, how can I have smooth transition between images like this?
I tried using Moti animation. But it feels like I am only fading in and out the images
MotiView
    key={`image-${index}`}
    from={{
        opacity: 0,
    }}
    animate={{
        opacity: 1,
    }}
    exit={{
        opacity: 0,
    }}
    transition={{
        type: "timing",
        duration: 800,
    }}
    className="flex-1 items-center justify-center"
    >
    <Image
        source={imgPaths[index]}
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200, resizeMode: "contain" }}
    />
</MotiView>

